# Moving newly created groups to another OU directly with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script that creates 2 groups and immediatley moves them to an (already existing) OU.

I tried checking possible answers and it shouldn't be too difficult. However, the code that I managed to get along doesn't seem to work:

```
New-ADGroup -Name "Soccer players" -GroupScope Global
New-ADGroup -Name "Tennis players" -GroupScope Global
Get-ADGroupMember "Soccer players" -Recursive | Move-ADObject   –TargetPath "OU=SportGroups,DC=funsports,DC=local"
Get-ADGroupMember "Tennis players" -Recursive | Move-ADObject  –TargetPath "OU=SportGroups,DC=funsports,DC=local"
```

The groups get created but not moved to the OU

I have tried variations of playing with the quotes (at ADGroupMember and target),... But it never seems to work....

Where's my problem?

**UPDATE**

```
New-ADGroup -Name "Soccer players" -GroupScope Global  –Path "OU=SportGroups,DC=funsports,DC=local" 
New-ADGroup -Name "Tennis players" -GroupScope Global  –Path "OU=SportGroups,DC=funsports,DC=local"
```

Creates the groups but not in the SportGroups OU (but in the default 'users' container)

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` -> `Get-ADGroup`. Or put the groups into the correct OU upon creation, so you don't need to move them in the first place: `New-ADGroup -Path`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work Ansgar, I updated my post

Comment: That's not a hyphen in `–Path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to move the groups instead of their members:

```
$ou = 'OU=SportGroups,DC=funsports,DC=local'
Get-ADGroup 'Soccer players' | Move-ADObject –TargetPath $ou
```

Or you could place the groups in the correct OU upon creation, so you don't need to move them in the first place:

```
$ou = 'OU=SportGroups,DC=funsports,DC=local'
New-ADGroup -Name 'Soccer players' -Path $ou -GroupScope Global
```